# Alternative to Mozilla Prism for Windows

Tags: windows, firefox, mozilla-prism

Since Mozila Prism and WebRunner are not longer active, I would like to ask you—What is the alternative for the same functionality for Firefox and Windows OS?

I know some alternatives are:

- Chrome > Create application shortcuts...
- Create shortcut manually by Windows functionality: New > Shortcut
- There is also Fluid application, but available for Mac OS X only

I'm looking for a functionality of adding website shortcut to taskbar/start menu/desktop.

Comment: What functionality do you mean exactly? Running XUL apps? Running HTML apps? Adding shortcuts to webpages?

Comment: or possibly a single site browswer

Comment: I added more details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging the website icon from the Navigation Bar, and dropping it on desktop will create
an internet shortcut file there.

Comment: That's a good tip. From this point, how can I pin this shortcut to taskbar? It attaches to Firefox automatically.